# mvvm model with additional property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am writing a wpf application using mvvm pattern for first time. So as per the pattern I have introduced fields that match the database table field. But I require some extra fields to be displayed in view. For instance I will compare Class A > Prop x with Class B > Prop y and if it matches I will display that result in UI along with Class A properties. So my question is can if i can include the extra property to hold this comparison value in model - class A itself, or create a wrapper of model class in view model and then add these extra field.

Both ways work for me, but what is the right way as per mvvm is what i dont get.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put any new properties on the model classes.  If your new property is truly a presentation-layer concern -- i.e. it's only for display purposes (read-only) or it can be updated by the user (read/write) but its value has no bearing on the business logic of the application -- then you want to add the property just on the view model.

The model shouldn't know or care that it's even being displayed somewhere or that its data is being manipulated for the purposes of display or user interaction.

Comment: Sounds great.. so can i add a class in view model which inherits model class and then add extra properties and use it in view ?

Comment: I would recommend separate classes.  The model typically has properties and behavior not relevant to the view model and vice versa.